# Take screenshot from AirDroid

Tags: screenshots, airdroid

I really need to know what other apps my child is using because I see him using his phone on a camera, but I don't know what does he do. Is he playing a game, working on some apps, or browsing... so, how to work with screenshot in AirDroid app?

Comment: Most of the operations you are talking about require rooting the device, which, depending on the company, could invalidate its warrantee. Is that going to be a concern?

Comment: Is [AirMirror](http://help.airdroid.com/customer/portal/articles/1784666-airmirror) the feature that you want?